# Orientation of frames generated by consistent charts in a common point

Tags: smooth-manifolds, coordinate-systems, orientation

I have a smooth $k$-surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and two charts $\varphi_1:I_t^n\to U_1\subset S$, $\varphi_2:I_\tau^n\to U_2\subset S$ with $U_1\cap U_2\neq \emptyset$ ($I^n$ is the unit open cube in $\mathbb{R}^n$). Picked a point $\underbrace{x_0}_{\in U_1\cap U_2}=\varphi_1(\underbrace{t_0}_{\in I_t^n})=\varphi_2(\underbrace{\tau_0}_{\in I_\tau^n})$ in such intersection, we know that if the two charts have positive transitions at $x_0$, then the induced two frames in $x_0$ by the two charts have the same orientation (and viceversa). Matematically this statement is written as:

$\text{sign}\det \left([\varphi_2^{-1}\circ \varphi_1]'(t_0)\right)=\text{sign}\det \left([\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]'(\tau_0)\right)>0\iff$ the two frames $F_{\varphi_1}=\{\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_n\}$ and $F_{\varphi_2}=\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_n\}$ induced by the two charts in $x_0$ are such that $\text{sign}\det \left(M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}\right)=\text{sign}\det \left(M_{F_{\varphi_2}\to F_{\varphi_1}}\right)>0$.

I remind that:

1. $\left\{\begin{matrix}
   \mathbf{b}_1=a_{11}\mathbf{e}_1+...+a_{1n}\mathbf{e}_n \\
   ...\\
   \mathbf{b}_n=a_{n1}\mathbf{e}_1+...+a_{nn}\mathbf{e}_n
   \end{matrix}\right.\iff M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}=\left(\begin{matrix}a_{11} & ...&a_{1n}\\
   ...&...&...\\
   a_{n1} & ...&a_{nn}\end{matrix}\right)$;
2. $M_{F_{\varphi_2}\to F_{\varphi_1}}=M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}^{-1}$;
3. $\mathbf{e}_i=\varphi_1'(t_0)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_i\\...\\0_n\end{matrix}\right)$, $i=1,...,n$;
4. $\mathbf{b}_i=\varphi_2'(\tau_0)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_i\\...\\0_n\end{matrix}\right)$, $i=1,...,n$.

Now, my question...

I would prove also the following proposition for the tangent space at $S$ in $x_0$ (namely $TS_{x_0}$):

The two charts have positive transitions at $x_0\iff$ the induced two frames for $TS_{x_0}$ by the two charts have the same orientation.

My book (Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II, 1st ed., Page 173) says that it's true but I can't find a plausible reason to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I believe you want $I^k$, not $I^n$ and all the indexes ranging from $1,\ldots, k$.)

Claim: The matrix  $M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}$ and the matrix $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]'(t_0)$ are transposes of each other.

Proof: Consider the image of the vector $\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_i\\...\\0_k\end{matrix}\right)$ under $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]'$. The idea of the proof is that by chain rule, we can first map it by $\varphi_2'(\tau_0)$  (and it goes to $\mathbf{b}_i$), and then take the resulting vector

$\mathbf{b}_i=a_{i1}\mathbf{e}_1+...+a_{ik}\mathbf{e}_k$

and map it by $(\varphi_1^{-1})'(x_0)$ considered as a map from $TS_{x_0}$ to $TI^k_{\tau_0}$, which is the inverse of $(\varphi_1)'(t_0)$ (considered as map to $TS_{x_0}$), and so sends it to $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{i1}\\...\\a_{ik}\end{matrix}\right)$ (since it's linear and sends each $\mathbf{e}_j$ to $\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_k\end{matrix}\right)$).

Thus the matrix of $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]'$ has $i$th column equal to $\left(\begin{matrix}a_{i1}\\...\\a_{ik}\end{matrix}\right)$,  proving the claim.

This is a rigorous argument once one knows the appropriate chain rule. To avoid this more advanced version of chain rule, one can argue as follows:

Extend each $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to maps $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$ from $I^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ (using Proposition on page 162).  Moreover, extend $(\mathbf{e_1},\ldots, \mathbf{e_k})$ to a basis or $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we write $\Phi_1'(t_0)$ using the standard basis on $TI^k_{t_0}$ and this newly constructed basis on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We have that $\Phi_1'(t_0)$ is block upper-triangular, with a $k$ by $k$ upper left block being identity, corresponding to the fact that

$$[\Phi_1'(t_0)](\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_n\end{matrix}\right))=[\phi_1'(t_0)](\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_k\end{matrix}\right))=\mathbf{e}_j$$  for $j=1, \ldots, k$.

Similarly, $\Phi_2'(\tau_0)$ is block upper-triangular, with a $k$ by $k$ upper left block being $\left(M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}\right)^T$, corresponding to

$$[\Phi_2'(\tau_0)](\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_n\end{matrix}\right))=[\phi_2'(\tau_0)](\left(\begin{matrix}0_1\\...\\1_j\\...\\0_k\end{matrix}\right))=\mathbf{b}_j=\sum a_{ji}\mathbf{e}_i$$  for $j=1, \ldots, k$.

Then, by chain rule applied to $[\Phi_1^{-1} \cdot \Phi_2]$ we have that the $n$ by $n$ matrix $[\Phi_1^{-1} \cdot \Phi_2 (\tau)]'$ is composition of two $n$ by $n$ matrices  $ [\Phi_2'] (\tau_0)$ and $[\Phi_1^{-1}]'(x_0)$. Both of these are block-upper-triangular, with the $k$ by $k$ left upper block of $ [\Phi_2'] (\tau_0)$ equal to $\left(M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}\right)^T$ and the $k$ by $k$ left upper block of $[\Phi_1^{-1}]'(x_0)$ equal to inverse of identity, i.e. identity. Then we conclude that the $k$ by $k$ left upper block of $[\Phi_1^{-1} \cdot \Phi_2]$, being product of these two $k$ by $k$ blocks, is also just $\left(M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}}\right)^T$.

But this block is of course just $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]'(\tau_0)$, since the map $[\Phi_1^{-1} \cdot \Phi_2]$ restricted to $I^k$ is $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ \varphi_2]$.

This reproves the claim (using onluy chain rule for maps between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Now from the claim the result follows, since transpose matrices have the same determinant.

Comment: No, the matrix $[\varphi_1^{-1}\circ\varphi_2]'(t_0)$ has dimension $n\times n$ and the matrix $ M_{F_{\varphi_1}\to F_{\varphi_2}} $ has dimension $k\times k$.
In fact, the frame generated by a chart at a point is composed by $n$ linear independent vectors, but only $k$ of these $n$ are in (generates) $TS_{x_0}$.

Comment: ...at least, this is what I have understood from what I have studied, of course I can be wrong...

Comment: Usual definition of a chart says it is a homeomorphism to (or, sometimes, from) a piece of a surface/manifold. As a homeomorphism, it better map between things that have the same dimension, and you are working with a k-surface. I believe Zorich is using the same definition.

Comment: There could be differences in definitions, but any reasonable definition would hard to square away with what you have written in the question (i.e. $\varphi_1:I_t^n\to U_1\subset S$ etc.) without modifying something.

Comment: Zorich uses the following def. for smooth k-surfaces:
A set $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth k-surface if for each point $x\in S$ there exists a diffeomorphism $\varphi:I^n\to U(x)$ such that every point of $U(x)$ is described by $(t_1,...,t_k,0,...,0)$ under $\varphi$. In other words, the diffeomorphism is between points of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the points of the surface have the property that they are the image of points in $I^n$ with the last n-k coordinates equals to 0.

Comment: Your terminology does not distinguish between neighborhood of $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and in $S$. These are different. A smooth surface has both "ambient charts" between neighborhoods in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $U^n$ and surface charts between $I^k$ and pieces of the surface.  Orientations of the surface usually have to do with the later ones. However this does not affect the above argument.

Comment: Ok, so I'm referring only to ambient charts. Your arguments (with k=n) proves that the whole transition matrix ($n\times n$) from $\{\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_n\}$ to $\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_n\}$ (and viceversa) has positive determinant, but how can we prove that also the transition matrix ($k\times k$) from $\{\mathbf{e}_1,...,\mathbf{e}_k\}$ to $\{\mathbf{b}_1,...,\mathbf{b}_k\}$ (and viceversa) has positive determinant?

Comment: You can't since it's not true. Consider the $k=1, n=2$, $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2| y=0\}$, $\phi_1(x,y)=(x, y)$, $\phi_2(x,y)=(-x, -y)$. The ambient matrix is 2 by 2 minus identity, det is 1; the k by k matrix is -1.

Comment: BTW, I have failed to find the discussion you refer to in Zorich. Are you using the first English edition? Or Russian one? Is it really page 173?

Comment: Zorich, Mathematical Analysis II, 1st english ed., pag. 172 (where he talks about domains $G\subset \mathbb{R}^n$):

"It is not difficult to verify that curvilinear coordinate systems belonging to the same orientation class generate continuous fields of frames in $G$ (as described above) that are in the same orientation class of the tangent space $TG_x$ at each point $x\in G$."

Comment: At the next page he says:

"What has just been said about the orientation of a domain $G\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ can be repeated verbatim if instead of the domain $G$ we consider a smooth k-dimensional surface $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by a single chart."

Comment: Yes, and the chart he refers to is as in figure 12.7, with domain $I^k$ (as indicated in the picture); this is a chart in the sense of Definition 12.1.2, p. 161, as modified to have domain $I^k$ on top of p. 162. (formula 12.1).

Comment: Then $\varphi_1’(t_0)$ is not a square matrix, because it maps points of $\mathbb{R}^k$ into points of $\mathbb{R}^n$. No?

Comment: That's right if one considers maps $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ as mapping to $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we consider them as mapping to $S$ then their derivatives map to $TS_{x_0}$, as in picture 12.7. I now realize you may not have the appropriate chain rule available; I will modify the answer to work around this.

Comment: Ok thanks. I would inform you that at my level I know surfaces only as surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$. So I can’t really understand what you mean with “consider them as mapping to S”.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112605/discussion-between-max-and-nameless).